# Overwrite browser language with RequestHook

Tags: javascript, request, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm writing tests on a web application that supports multiple languages through the browser settings.

I've written a `RequestHook` that overwrites the `Accept-Language` header. However, this does not seem to work. The language always seems to be en-US (I guess from my system?)

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
class LanguageRequestHook extends RequestHook {
    constructor(language, requestFilterRules) {
        super(requestFilterRules, {
            includeHeaders: true,
            includeBody: true});
        this.language = language;
    }
    async onRequest(event) {
        event.requestOptions.headers['Accept-Language'] = this.language;
    }
    async onResponse(responseEvent) {
        //Nothing
    }
}

const dutchLanguageHook = new LanguageRequestHook('nl-NL');

fixture('hook test').page('https://www.wikipedia.org/').requestHooks(dutchLanguageHook);

test('test dutch wiki', async t => {
    await t.expect(Selector('.localized-slogan').innerText).eql('De vrije encyclopedie');
});
```

With my `RequestHook` I would expect the request to indicate that it wants the Dutch Wikipedia page instead of the English version. The `RequestHook` does get called in my debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Make sure that you can set up the language by changing the 'Accept-Language' header on the web site you are testing. 
The example you provided doesn't work because the Wikipedia web site doesn't support the language set up by changing the 'Accept-Language' header. 
You can check this by running the following script:

```js
const rp      = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const options = {
    url: 'https://www.wikipedia.org/',

    headers: {
        'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL'
    }
};

rp(options)
    .then(body => {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    })
    .then($ => {
        console.log($('.localized-slogan').text());
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Wikipedia uses JS APIs like `navigator.language` to determine your language. Try to  set a conditional breakpoint at line 9 of Wikipedia's index HTML file with the following expression: `Object.defineProperties(navigator,{language:{value:'nl-NL'},languages:{value:['nl-NL']}}),null` and press F5 to reload the page.